# Regarding UML diagrams and patterns?

Tags: uml

I have a general UML question. I am studying a course in programming and the theme is pattern. So I would like to know if UML is connected somehow with patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. And no. You will likely see all design patterns drawn as diagrams. For example, the [GOF](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/31171684) (which is the reference book on the topic) does not use regular UML (because it was first published in 1995) but a representation very similar to class diagrams.

This is because you can draw the [blueprint](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlAsBlueprint.html) (which the class diagram represents) very easily with UML. You can then use that blueprint directly for your design and transform it to any code you want.

Comment: @bdulac Thanks for the edit. Nicely that blueprint now actually appears in blue ;o)